# Php Laravel Print paper

Tags: php, laravel

My website is related to flight tickets, after booking the ticket and ticket gets issued if i want to print the ticket, it is showing the paths of the buttons in agent panel like this ->
welcome agent,
Profile (http://localhost/tb/customer/dashboard)
MarkUp (http://localhost/tb/agent/markup/list)
Dashboard (localhost/tb)
reports (localhost/tb/list)

View Ticket Details
after all these, ticket details are printing.

Comment: Which code you are using to print the ticket?

Comment: function print_ticket() {
        window.print();
    }

Comment: What is the question? What is your code? How is this related to Laravel? Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: I suggest the batter way print data by create PDF and print it..

Comment: ok thanks. can you suggest me the code how to create pdf

Answer (score 1):

I like [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com/how-it-works) for this kind of thing. Send an API request with some HTML/CSS/Javascript and you get back a PDF with which you can do anything you want, including presenting to the user for download/printing.

They even provide a [PHP class](https://docraptor.com/try_it_out) to handle API access.

It's a pay service, but it is worth every penny.

Generating a PDF locally has never worked well for me. Between the formatting problems that arise with different libraries, lack of Javascript support, and the resources consumed by the process, it was just too inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create PDF and then print the view, try this PDF generation plugin such as [pdf-laravel](https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5). This is just a DOMPDF module for Laravel 5.

*To get this pdf-laravel5 plugin, run below composer command*:

```
composer require vsmoraes/laravel-pdf
```

*To add provider, update `config/app.php` with below line to `providers` array*:

```
'PDF' => 'Vsmoraes\Pdf\PdfFacade',
```

*To generate out file:*

```
$router->get('/pdf/output', function() { 
    $html = view('pdfs.example')->render();

    PDF::load($html)
        ->filename('/tmp/example1.pdf')
        ->output();

    return 'PDF saved';

});
```

*Inject on your controller:*

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Vsmoraes\Pdf\Pdf;

class HomeController extends BaseControler
{
    private $pdf;

    public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    public function helloWorld()
    {
        $html = view('pdfs.example1')->render();

        return $this->pdf
            ->load($html)
            ->show();
    }
}
```

*You can also force to download PDF like:*

```
$router->get('/pdf/download', function() {
    $html = view('pdfs.example')->render();

    return PDF::load($html)->download();
});
```

Comment: We tried local PDF generation for our invoices and we wound up going with DocRaptor. It was just too resource-intensive to locally create the PDFs, especially considering that we processed them in batches. Trying to create hundreds of PDFs a minute slowed us to a crawl. Better to outsource that sort of thing to a dedicated service. We also had formatting issues with both PhantomJS and DOMPDF, and neither worked right with javascript.